# What do you call someone or something that generates insights?

Tags: single-word-requests, business-language

What is the appropriate word for someone (or something) that gives you insights?

Example sentences for context:

> Ann is our best ???. She always provides us with amazing insights.

> This software is a good ???. It helps us to get brilliant insights into our business process.

What would you replace "???" with? Something that conveys the meaning and is commonly understood (mainly in business and formal/semi-formal environments).

Comment: Is that an analyst?

Comment: @YosefBaskin well, an analyst is a little broad and only applies to a person. You can't really use "analyst" to describe a thing. Also, not every analyst generates insights. I was hoping that maybe there's something that is more specific and expressive

Comment: [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/inspiration) has << **inspiration**: the process of being mentally stimulated to do [I'd add 'see'] or feel something, especially to do something creative.
"Helen had one of her flashes of inspiration" >> and [again](https://www.lexico.com/definition/inspirational)<< **inspirational**: providing or showing creative or spiritual inspiration. >> But 'inspirer' sounds off here.

Comment: Duh!!  A microscope!!!

Comment: Can you explain the distinction you are drawing between "insight" and what an analyst generates? I'm having conceptual trouble here because both *analyst* and *insight* feel broad - they both relate to finding things that were not initially or superficially known.

Comment: @TaliesinMerlin thanks, your comment makes a lot of sense. What I mean is that kind of insight that is sort of discovery. Something that triggers new ideas, creates new knowledge, etc. Insight by definition means "clear, deep understanding" of something. Analysis often may be just breaking things down to smaller items, describing and documenting them. Not necessarilly leading to a "deep understanding". Often analysis may result in insights but not always.

Comment: How about perceptive? You can also go to tired slang, e.g., thinking out of the box.

Comment: Someone that generates insights is a _muse_. But there isn't any thing that can do that, though there are places and events that can.

Comment: @JohnLawler thank you! Your comment makes me realise that actually, insight is not something that can be generated or created externally. Rather it is something that happens in one's mind. Insights can be stimulated or even provoked by some external influence but that's not guaranteed. Perhaps I need to reconsider the way I try to use this word and what is it I am trying to say. Thank you very much everyone for your comments!

Comment: She is our best prognosticator.

Answer (score 1):

My answer is "oracle" because the dictionary's (to wit, Oxford) foremost definition includes, "a person or thing regarded as an infallible authority or guide on something". And that is how I have always heard it used.

Comment: If you've actually read the [Tour], you ought to know :) In any case, it's not important to the answer, so I'll remove your 'comment'. Secondly, can you expand on your answer? What's the definition of 'oracle', and why do you think it fits the OP's request?

Answer (score 1):

`perspicacious` is  a word you will see whenever deep and instant insight is there. It appears often in books and prints. However, I have seldom seen it in business or technical communication (which may or may not be a plus point in your context )

Also, I understand it is not a drop-in replacement for the ??? in your sentence. But the sentence can be reworded as XYZ is a perspicacious analyst.

The Noun form is `Perspicacity`.

```
perspicacious
/ˌpəːspɪˈkeɪʃəs/
adjective
adjective: perspicacious

    having a ready insight into and understanding of things.
    "it offers quite a few facts to the perspicacious reporter"
```

```
/ˌpərspɪˈkeɪʃəs/ 
(formal)
 
able to understand someone or something quickly and accurately; showing this a perspicacious remark He was perspicacious enough to realize that things were soon going to change.
```

Comment: If adjectives are to be allowed, 'insightful' is hard to better.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth. True. insightful will also go with both- a person  or a  software .  Though it will still not be an in-place replacement for ??? in OP's sentence

Answer (score -2):

Recognizing this is an old post, if you look up synonyms for the word "sage" you should find some potential options. Something like "authority" might be simple and accessible in many uses.

From M-W:

[sage](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sage) noun (1)

> **1**
> : one (such as a profound philosopher) distinguished for wisdom
>
> **2**
> : a mature or venerable person of sound judgment

[authority](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/authority)

> **4** **a**
> **(1)**
> : a citation (as from a book or file) used in defense or support
> **(2)**
> : the source from which the citation is drawn
>
> **b**
> **(1)**
> : a conclusive statement or set of statements (such as an official decision of a court) 
> **(2)**
> : a decision taken as a precedent 
> **(3)**
> : TESTIMONY 
> **c**
> : an individual cited or appealed to as an expert

Comment: Hi Kevin. Users generally come here for direct answers, not to look something up (which is something we assume they have done already themselves).  Also, 'authority' intrinsically has nothing to do with generating insight - why do you think it fits the OP's request?